# How to write the cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, actionmailer

I'm trying to set up cron job without using "Whenever" in development environment.
I checked log and cron seems working in each 2 minutes but no mail was sent...
How can I correctly write the cron job?

models/box.rb:

```
def self.reminder_mail
    @boxes = Box.all
    @boxes.each do |box|
      if box.status == "PENDING"
          NoticeMailer.sendmail_reminder(box).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

Crontab

```
*/2 * * * *  ubuntu /home/ubuntu/workspace/box/reminder_mail
```

cronlog

```
Feb 25 11:10:01 ubuntu-xenial CRON[4599]: (ubuntu) CMD (ubuntu /home/ubuntu/workspace/box/reminder_mail)
Feb 25 11:10:01 ubuntu-xenial CRON[4598]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 25 11:12:01 ubuntu-xenial CRON[4605]: (ubuntu) CMD (ubuntu /home/ubuntu/workspace/box/reminder_mail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem! 
Important is to write rake PATH in my case `/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims` directly into PATH and not mention into cron job.

`*/2 *   * * *   ubuntu  cd /home/ubuntu/workspace/box && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake reminder_task:reminder_mail >> /home/ubuntu/workspace/box/log/cron.log`

Answer (score 1):

Your cronlog is giving you explanation: there is no MTA in your development system.  MTA stands for Mail Transfer Agent, a system service that relays emails sent by clients like the cron job.

If you can, install and configure postfix, which is a very popular MTA.

## Update

Your cron file is wrong, change RAILS_ENV=production to be first, something like this `RAILS_ENV=production rake reminder_task:reminder_email`.

Also, if your project is using bundler use `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake reminder_task:reminder_email` — this will allow to run your rake task with access to all required gems etc. I think you don't have to change working directory, neither. Instead, put a line like this in the cron file:

```
HOME=/path/to/your/project
```

Comment: Thanks! With shell command it's working so it seems not MTA problem.  Is it PATH problem???  If I use Whenever, I normally write "env :PATH, ENV['PATH']" in schedule.rb.  I tried to write cron job " * * * * * . ~/.profile;/home/ubuntu//workspace/box/reminder_mail " however it's also not working...

Comment: Calling model method from a cron job will not work. Why not start from fresh rake task (use `rails g task reminder_task reminder_email` to generate a task `lib/tasks/reminder_task.rb`, which you can further change to your needs. Perhaps you have some code generated by Whenever gem that you are not aware of (like cron file), have a look inside `/etc/cron.d/` of your system.

Comment: Thanks! I created rake task and if I enter a command "rake reminder_task:reminder_mail", then reminder_mail was sent only one time. It means cron task is not working. Is it correct way to write rake task on crontab  "*/2 * * * * ubuntu cd /home/ubuntu/workspace/box/reminder_task && /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/rake RAILS_ENV=production reminder_task:reminder_mail" ??

Comment: Thanks a lot, adass! I followed your explanation and solved! I posted my final cron job.

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround you can implement an API and use curl to execute it with a custom authorization inside the method just to authorize the request

then add th curl request inside your crontab

```
*/2 * * * *  curl --silent {you can spesify if it was POST,GET..etc} http://example.com/{your API path}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried with */2 * * * * curl --silent home/ubuntu/workspace/box/reminder_mail http://localhost:3000, but not working...

Comment: the API request doesn't call like what you wrote it called like this curl {your ip}:{port number}/{path_extension}

Comment: Do you mean " */2 * * * * curl --silent http://localhost:3000/home/ubuntu/workspace/box/reminder_mail "?